# What is the significance of the two letter shins (ש) on tefillin?

Tags: tefilin, aleph-bet-letters

What is the significance of the two letter shins (ש) on tefillin?

One side of tefillin has a regular shin (ש) and the second has four-prongs.

[image: tefillin with regular shin (3 prongs)]
[image: tefillin with four-pronged shin]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [here](http://www.vbm-torah.org/archive/mb/18mb.htm), quoting the Beit Yosef to Orach Chaim 32:

The Verse says, *"And all the nations of the land will see that the name of God is called upon you and they will fear you" (Devarim 28:10)*. The Talmud says that this refers to the the Tefillin Shel Rosh (Tefillin of the Head).

G-d Name, The Tetragramaton, is the numerical value of 300, using the Gematria Method known as [AT-BASH](http://hebrewetutor.com/gematria.html):

Yud == Mem (40)

Hey == Tzadi (90)

Vav == Peh (80)

Hey == Tzadi (90)

So the 3 pronged Shin represents G-d's name.

According to the Sefer Mitzvos Gedolos, quoted by the Beit Yosef, the writing in the Luchos (Tablets) were sunken in. If so, a Shin had 4 prongs, and the 4 progned Shin on the Tefillin Shel Rosh commemorates that.

The Talmud ([Menachot 35A](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=4458&size=2) - [page 130 of here](http://www.halakhah.com/pdf/kodoshim/Menachoth.pdf)) says:

> Abaye also said, The shin of the tefillin is a law given to Moses at Sinai

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall where I saw this, but essentially we have    **ש + ש + ו**    since the extra head of the Shin is a Vav.

This gives us a gematria of 606.

Now we add the 7 vertical bars that create the 2 Shins.

606 + 7 =613; corresponding to the 613 Mitzvoth.

Comment: i heard it like this ש300 + ש300 + 6שש + vertical bars7 = 613

Comment: 6 was from the word shesh not from the ו

Comment: @hazoriz - interesting - but what is the source? I've been scrounging around for it for a while now.