# Are women forbidden from Teaching Gemara\Talmud?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, women, torah-study

Assuming [that women are allowed to **learn** Gemara\Talmud\Torah she-Ba'al Peh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7071), are they still *forbidden* from **teaching** it to others (either men or women)?

Textual sources for (either references or links) would be greatly appreciated.  Sources explicitly stating that they **are** permitted would also be nice.

Comment: Could you explain why you think they might be forbidden?

Comment: Do you mean _qua_ tzniut or _qua_ talmud torah?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7071/759

Comment: @MonicaCellio-  I don't know why.  Someone mentioned it to me, and he seemed really certain about it.  I don't think they are (assuming they're permitted to learn), but I'd like sources either way.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Either, but more from Talmud Torah\Serara\'Tiflut' than from Tzniut.

Comment: If I had more time I'd write a meta question about this. It really irks me when I see "is x permitted" or "is y prohibited" questions that lean towards a presupposed answer, or at least a presupposed "ought", and it irks me to no end when the question further fails to outline any reason why the question is being brought (OK Q: Is stealing someone's naivete considered theft, since all the verses discussing theft refer to tangible things? A: Yes, Genevath Da'ath is discussed in Sefer X, Chapter Y...

Comment: As opposed to disingenuous Q: Is stealing someone's naivete permitted, since it's not _really_ stealing? A: Do us all a favor and stop asking for loopholes to take advantage of some unknowing victim.) *steps off soapbox*

Comment: @SethJ - If you have a better way to phrase this question, please let us know.

Comment: @SethJ - This is a request for sources that's phrased as a practical question.  I feel that phrasing things in clear Yes\No terms is a better approach than simply asking "Does anyone know anything about this?" .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are stories of women teaching from behind a mechitza (I believe Nechama Leibowitz did so?).

But here's one Gemara, Pesachim 62b:

> ר' שמלאי אתא לקמיה דרבי יוחנן. א"ל: *ניתני לי מר ספר יוחסין*

...

> *ניתנייה בג' ירחי!* 
>     שקל קלא פתק ביה א"ל: **ומה ברוריה דביתהו דר"מ ברתיה דר"ח בן תרדיון  דתניא תלת מאה שמעתתא ביומא מג' מאה רבוותא ואפ"ה לא יצתה ידי חובתה בתלת שנין**-- ואת אמרת בתלתא ירחי ?!
>
> Rabbi Samlai approached Rabbi Yochanan ... and requested that Rabbi Yochanan teach him *The Book of Lineages* in three months. Rabbi Yochanan replied: **Bruriah, the wife of Rabbi Meir and daughter of Rabbi Chananya ben Teradion, could teach 300 topics a day from 300 insights -- and even she couldn't do the entirety in three years!** You expect me to teach it to you in three months?!

Rashi says this *Book of Lineages* is: מתני' דדברי הימים. Our Oral teaching on Chronicles.

So the Gemara pretty much says that Bruriah taught this Talmud-like work (which is no longer extant). Make of that what you will.

Though see Alex's question and my response below -- some translate this as "she learned" rather than "she taught."

Comment: Quick, another answer for [300-mi-yodeya](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16183/shelosh-meyot-mi-yodeya)!

Comment: Does it mean that she *taught* these 300 topics, though, or that she *learned* them from the 300 teachers?

Comment: @Alex: thank you for challenging me on that. Soncino translates "she learned from 300 teachers." I'd read "she taught, using 300 expoundings" (as in "le-rabos.") Rashi says she couldn't "lishnosah", and two lines earlier writes "ein shonin ...", meaning "we don't teach." But I'd be fascinated to see the variant readings here.

Comment: @jake Already [taken](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16188/759).

Comment: "Note that the Gemarah and Rashi explains the story of Rabbi Meir and Bruriah where Bruriah was seduced by a talmid of Rabbi Meir after Rabbi Meir predicted this due to the fact that נשים דעתן קלות הן. Many meforshim explain that this was due to Bruriah learning Gemarah" -----Comment of another user.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if you consider it teaching,but the Drisha(Prisha) in his hakdama in Yoreh Deah describes a woman by the name of Beila either mother or his wife. She was really pious as he describes her and he brings two halchos from her regarding candle lighting. See Magen Avraham OC 263:12 to see a reference to that halacha.

Answer (score 2):

The Ramaz School in New York City, founded by and under the oversight of Rabbi Haskel Lookstein employs one female Gemara teacher. She teaches both boys and girls.