# Echad ushlosh meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred and one?

### ?אחד ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 301.

Anyone who posts an answer consisting of just the lazy gematria is fired.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous three hundred entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Comment: I don't know if I'd go so far as to _fire_ them, but I certainly would tell them to "SHA!"

Comment: Is there a master index somewhere of this series? (I mean other than [having to manually check each page](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series))

Comment: @ibid, if you sort the series tag list by "newest," you get them, with very few exceptions, lined up in reverse order.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - Has anyone (who, unlike me,  knows Hebrew) compiled it into a super extended version of the song?

Comment: @ibid, funny you should ask. We are doing a [little bit of that](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3982/2), in English though, for the forthcoming second edition of [*Hagada - Mi Yodeya?*](http://s.tk/miyodeya), with an [eye toward](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3751/2) doing the whole series in the future.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - Well, IMO it's kind of pointless if you don't have it in Hebrew. (Fun, but not very usable.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Umm, 301 men that defeated the Midianites in Judges 7 (Gideon + 300 more).

Comment: Also, then, the total number of people in Shechaniah ben Yechaziel's group http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16195/759

Comment: @DoubleAA true, go for it!

Comment: I'm afraid mine has less of a chance of qualifying as "interesting and significant".

Answer (score 5):

Sarah was born 301 years after the end of the Flood ([1657](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46817&pgnum=48)-[1958](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46817&pgnum=51)).

Answer (score 2):

301 is the [floor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_function) of the number of thousands of [*sh'kalim* given to the *mishkan*, half at a time](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9899/showrashi/true#v25).

Answer (score 1):

Tehillim 118:11 סבוני גם סבבוני "they encircle me and they also surround me" = 301.

Artscroll Tehillim to 118:11 (Vilna Gaon, Etz Yosef, Otzar HaTefillos) explain the 2 letter and 3 letter shoresh to mean "encircle from distance" and then "encircled tightly" referring to the Psalmist/Israel's enemies.