# Tish'a Asar Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred nineteen?

### ?תשעה עשר ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 319.

Please don't try to just sail through with lazy gematria.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous three hundred eighteen entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Comment: So you're taking the lazy gematrios off the table, huh?

Comment: @HodofHod :) I was going to try to work that in, too, but I didn't come up with something that would efficiently address both that and the Hebrew reference.

Comment: http://room404.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/internet-equals-cancer-photo-by-michael-zilberman.JPG

Comment: @GershonGold Hilarious :)

Comment: @Gershon, Avraham + 318 is 319, go for it! ([It's legal!](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16563/883))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the 319th year of the fourth millenium [AM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_Mundi), [Nebuchadnezzar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebuchadnezzar_II) conquered Jerusalem<sup>1</sup>, beginning the first of four exiles<sup>2</sup> that would envelop the Jews until today.

---

<sup>1. [Seder Hadorot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seder_HaDoroth), Fourth Millenium, [Year 319](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46817&pgnum=146).</sup>

<sup>2. Various midrashim on the [Covenant Between the Pieces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covenant_of_the_pieces), including [Pirkei Derabi Eli'ezer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirke_De-Rabbi_Eliezer) Chapter [28](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/pirkeyeliezer/pirkeyeliezer03.pdf).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

[Osniel Ben Kenaz](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%96) was the first Shofet after Yehoshua passed away. From the time of Osniel until the end of the time of Bnei Amon was 319 years. [(Kro Mikra page 330:10)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30800&st=&pgnum=282&hilite=)

Osniel ben Kenaz = 40 years ** Aihud ben Gaira = 80 years ** Devora = 40 years ** Gidon ben Yohash = 40 years ** Avimelech = 3 years ** Tolah ben Pua = 23 years ** Yair Hagiladi = 22 years ** 40 + 80 + 40 + 40 + 3 + 23 + 22 = 248

Kushan Rishosayim = 8 years ** Eglon Melech Moav = 18 years ** Yavin Melech Kenaan = 20 years ** Midyan = 7 years ** Bnei Amon = 18 years ** 8 + 18 + 20 + 7 + 18 = 71

248 + 71 = 319

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what the end of the time of Bnei Amon is?

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12439989#12439989

Comment: @msh210: I only know what I see in the linked Sefer. I am not an expert on that time frame and do not know how to clarify this further.

Answer (score 1):

In a ה״ש מעוברת, there will be 54 Shabbasos (excluding Shabbos Yom Kippur) plus 12 weekday Yamim Tovim (outside Eretz Yisrael), yielding 319 days on which Kiddush is not made.<sup>1</sup>

This number is particularly significant, as in this year type there are the maximum number of such Kiddushes possible. In any other leap year at least two Yamim Tovim will fall out on Shabbos.

<sup>1</sup>Kiddush *is* made on Yom Kippur for one who is not fasting. I speak here only about a normal case.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5784/759