# Where are the 24 places that Kohanim are called Leviim?

Tags: sources-mekorot, names, kohen-priest, levites-leviyim

In numerous places the gemara quotes Rabbi Yehoshua Ben Levi as saying there are 24 places that Kohanim are called Leviim, but the gemara only ever quotes the pasuk in [Yechezkel 44 15](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.44.15?with=all&lang=bi). See for instance [Yevamos 86b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.86b.1?with=Commentary&lang=bi)

> דאמר ר' יהושע ב"ל בעשרים וארבעה מקומות נקראו כהנים לוים וזה אחד מהם (יחזקאל מד, טו) והכהנים הלוים בני צדוק

The gemara goes out of its way to say this pasuk is only one of the twenty four places, but never mentions another.
This same quote appears in Chulin 24b, Bechoros 4a, and Tamid 27a.

To make things more confusing, in [Shar Hagilgulim chapter 35](https://www.sefaria.org/Sha%27ar_HaGilgulim.35?lang=bi), we are told no other Navi besides Yechezkel ever called the Kohanim by the name Leviim.

> ודע, כי לעתיד לבא, כל שרש קין יהיו כהנים. ושרש הבל שהיו עד עתה כהנים, אז יהיו לוים. באופן, כי כל מה שהיה עד עתה בחי' לוים מצד הגבורה, דוגמת קרח לוי, שהיה משרש קין, כלם יקחו אז את הכהונה, שהיא חלק הבכורה, כנודע מתרגום פסוק ראובן בכורי אתה. וז"ס פסוק והכהנים הלוים בני צדוק. **והנה לא נמצא בשום נביא, שיזכיר הכהנים בשם לוים, אלא ביחזקאל**, לפי שהוא היה משרש קין הבכור, כמבואר אצלינו. ולכן נבא נבואה זו, כי לעתיד לבא אותם שהיו עד עתה כהנים, יהיו אז לויים. וכן מי שהיו לויים, יהיו אז כהנים בני צדוק. וכל שרש הבל שעתה הם כהנים, יהיו אז לויים:,

Are there other places, 23 in fact, where Kohanim are called Leviim? Is Shar Hagilgulim arguing on the gemara?

Comment: Did you try searching for the phrase? Seems like the obvious first step and don't need everyone repeating it.

Comment: Sha'ar Hagilgulim, if taken in the way you understood it, is arguing on Moshe, Yehoshua and other authors of books of Tanach.

Comment: @רבות Why do you say he's arguing on anyone? Is there another way to read what he said? Seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: @user6591 I'm working on an answer, but  for now, Moshe was a Navi who referred to Kohanim as "Leviyim" a few times in the Torah. Perhaps Sha'ar Hagilgulim is suggesting that they were never referred to in this manner in a Nevuah?

Comment: At least some of them are are presumably the very pesukim discussed in the Gemaros you cite.

Comment: So that's at least five instances right off the bat.

Comment: Regarding this number, perhaps https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100032/16354 is relevant

Answer (score 8):

I could not find any mainstream commentary which listed them.

Based on a search, I found 14 cases where they are explicitly referred to as Kohanim Haleviyim, with a couple more questionable (unlikely) cases:

1. Devarim 17:9 - וּבָאתָ אֶל הַכֹּהֲנִים הַלְוִיִּם וְאֶל הַשֹּׁפֵט אֲשֶׁר יִהְיֶה בַּיָּמִים הָהֵם וְדָרַשְׁתָּ וְהִגִּידוּ לְךָ אֵת דְּבַר הַמִּשְׁפָּט.
2. Devarim 17:18 - וְהָיָה כְשִׁבְתּוֹ עַל כִּסֵּא מַמְלַכְתּוֹ וְכָתַב לוֹ אֶת מִשְׁנֵה הַתּוֹרָה הַזֹּאת עַל סֵפֶר מִלִּפְנֵי הַכֹּהֲנִים הַלְוִיִּם.
3. Devarim 18:1 - לֹא יִהְיֶה לַכֹּהֲנִים הַלְוִיִּם כׇּל שֵׁבֶט לֵוִי חֵלֶק וְנַחֲלָה עִם יִשְׂרָאֵל אִשֵּׁי י״י וְנַחֲלָתוֹ יֹאכֵלוּן.
4. Devarim 24:8 - הִשָּׁמֶר בְּנֶגַע הַצָּרַעַת לִשְׁמֹר מְאֹד וְלַעֲשׂוֹת כְּכֹל אֲשֶׁר יוֹרוּ אֶתְכֶם הַכֹּהֲנִים הַלְוִיִּם כַּאֲשֶׁר צִוִּיתִם תִּשְׁמְרוּ לַעֲשׂוֹת.
5. Devarim 27:9 - וַיְדַבֵּר מֹשֶׁה וְהַכֹּהֲנִים הַלְוִיִּם אֶל כׇּל יִשְׂרָאֵל לֵאמֹר הַסְכֵּת וּשְׁמַע יִשְׂרָאֵל הַיּוֹם הַזֶּה נִהְיֵיתָ לְעָם לַי״י אֱלֹהֶיךָ.
6. Yehoshua 3:3 - וַיְצַוּוּ אֶת הָעָם לֵאמֹר כִּרְאֹתְכֶם אֵת אֲרוֹן בְּרִית י״י אֱלֹהֵיכֶם וְהַכֹּהֲנִים הַלְוִיִּם נֹשְׂאִים אֹתוֹ וְאַתֶּם תִּסְעוּ מִמְּקוֹמְכֶם וַהֲלַכְתֶּם אַחֲרָיו.
7. Yehoshua 8:33 - וַיַּעֲלוּ אֶת אֲרוֹן י״י וְאֶת אֹהֶל מוֹעֵד וְאֶת כׇּל כְּלֵי הַקֹּדֶשׁ אֲשֶׁר בָּאֹהֶל וַיַּעֲלוּ אֹתָם הַכֹּהֲנִים וְהַלְוִיִּם.
8. Yirmiyahu 33:18 - וְלַכֹּהֲנִים הַלְוִיִּם לֹא יִכָּרֵת אִישׁ מִלְּפָנָי מַעֲלֶה עוֹלָה וּמַקְטִיר מִנְחָה וְעֹשֶׂה זֶּבַח כׇּל הַיָּמִים.
9. Yechezkel 43:19 - וְנָתַתָּה אֶל הַכֹּהֲנִים הַלְוִיִּם אֲשֶׁר הֵם מִזֶּרַע צָדוֹק הַקְּרֹבִים אֵלַי נְאֻם אֲדֹנָי יֱ־הֹוִה לְשָׁרְתֵנִי פַּר בֶּן בָּקָר לְחַטָּאת.
10. Yechezkel 44:15 - וְהַכֹּהֲנִים הַלְוִיִּם בְּנֵי צָדוֹק אֲשֶׁר שָׁמְרוּ אֶת מִשְׁמֶרֶת מִקְדָּשִׁי בִּתְעוֹת בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל מֵעָלַי הֵמָּה יִקְרְבוּ אֵלַי לְשָׁרְתֵנִי וְעָמְדוּ לְפָנַי לְהַקְרִיב לִי חֵלֶב וָדָם נְאֻם אֲדֹנָי יֱ־הֹוִה.
11. Ezra 10:5 - וַיָּקׇם עֶזְרָא וַיַּשְׁבַּע אֶת שָׂרֵי הַכֹּהֲנִים הַלְוִיִּם וְכׇל יִשְׂרָאֵל לַעֲשׂוֹת כַּדָּבָר הַזֶּה וַיִּשָּׁבֵעוּ.
12. Divrei Hayamim Bet 5:5 - וַיַּעֲלוּ אֶת הָאָרוֹן וְאֶת אֹהֶל מוֹעֵד וְאֶת כׇּל כְּלֵי הַקֹּדֶשׁ אֲשֶׁר בָּאֹהֶל הֶעֱלוּ אֹתָם הַכֹּהֲנִים הַלְוִיִּם.
13. Divrei Hayamim Bet 23:18 - וַיָּשֶׂם יְהוֹיָדָע פְּקֻדּוֹת בֵּית י״י בְּיַד הַכֹּהֲנִים הַלְוִיִּם אֲשֶׁר חָלַק דָּוִיד עַל בֵּית י״י לְהַעֲלוֹת עֹלוֹת י״י כַּכָּתוּב בְּתוֹרַת מֹשֶׁה בְּשִׂמְחָה וּבְשִׁיר עַל יְדֵי דָוִיד.
14. Divrei Hayamim Bet 30:27 - וַיָּקֻמוּ הַכֹּהֲנִים הַלְוִיִּם וַיְבָרְכוּ אֶת הָעָם וַיִּשָּׁמַע בְּקוֹלָם וַתָּבוֹא תְפִלָּתָם לִמְעוֹן קׇדְשׁוֹ לַשָּׁמָיִם.

(Very) Questionable: Yeshayah 66:21, Nechemiah 10:29, 10:35, Divrei Hayamim Aleph 9:2

Even though there are only 14 of those, in Yevamot, the the Gemara itself brings this up in a discussion of Bamidbar 18:26, which only says the word "Leviyim", and the Gemara understands it to be referring to Kohanim. In Bechorot, it is brought up referring to Bamidbar 3:12, 3:39, 3:45. In Chullin, it is brought up referring to Ezra 3:8. In Tamid, it is brought up referring to Divrei Hayamim Aleph 26:17 (which may have multiple cases).

Additionally, Torah Temimah proves from Bava Kamma 108b that Devarim 18:6 also refers to Kohanim. Rashi in Sukkah 55b (d.h. uvah) also writes that Devarim 18:7 refers to Kohanim. Sheyarei Korban to Yerushalmi Sotah 8:3 writes that according to the Yerushalmi, Divrei Hayamim Bet 35:3 also refers to Kohanim.

Thus it is possible to assemble a list of 24 places in which Kohanim are referred to as Leviyim, especially if we consider separate mentions in the same paragraph or section to be multiple cases.

I have no resolution to explain the Sha'ar Hagilgulim's statement, which is at clear odds with the Gemara and Pesukim. I have no idea how he resolves cases in Yirmiyahu and Yehoshua.

Edit: I searched Otzar, and found one author (Harei Yehudah Volume 2 page 14) suggest that none are as explicit as Yechezkel, since he mentions Tzadok, who was a Kohen, by name, and refers to him as a Levi, whereas in all other places, it refers to Kohanim/Leviyim in general.

Comment: Itmay be worth comparing this to Berachot 19a where the same R. Yehoshua Ben Levi claims that there are 24 instances of something. When the Gemara there is unable to identify the vast majority of the cases, it concludes רבי יהושע בן לוי מדמה מילתא למילתא — in other words the count of 24 is only true if you include non-explicit cases.

Comment: Melachim 1:8:3 says the Kohanim carried the Aron at the ceremony when the Beis Hamikdash was completed. Divrei Hayamim 2:5:4 describing the same event says that the Leviim carried the Aron. Leviim, then, apparently refers to Kohanim. Indeed Ralbag says this explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason everyone seems to be focus on the examples of "כהנים לוים" meaning "כהנים"; however, I found a number of places where the pasuk literally says just plain (לוי(ם and the meforshim say that it really means (כהנ(ים. (I discovered these while researching the claims of modern/academic biblical scholarship that, originally, any Levi could become a Kohen [I.E. even those who were not descendants of Aaron]):

### **1. [II Divrei HaYamim 5:4 (based on I Melachim 8:3)](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.8.3?&lang=bi&p2=II_Chronicles.5.4&lang2=bi):**

II Divrei HaYamim 5:4

> ויקהלו אל־המלך כל־איש ישראל בחג הוא החדש השבעי: ויבאו כל זקני ישראל וישאו **הלוים** את־הארון

is contradicted by I Melachim 8:3

> ויקהלו אל־המלך שלמה כל־איש ישראל בירח האתנים בחג הוא החדש השביעי: ויבאו כל זקני ישראל וישאו **הכהנים** את־הארון

[Ralbag](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.8.3&lang=bi&p2=Ralbag_on_I_Kings.8.3.1&lang2=bi) & [Abarbanel](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.8.3?lang=bi&p2=Abarbanel_on_I_Kings.8.3.1&lang2=bi) on I Melachim 8:3 note this & write:

> **"מצינו שנקראו הכהנים לויים במקומות מה"**

Metzudas Dovid & Radak on II Chronicles 5:4 write similarly, and apparently, [some versions of Targum on II Chronicles have כהניא](https://www.sefaria.org/Targum_of_II_Chronicles.5.4) (Interestingly, the Radak on II Chronicles is the only one to reference the Gemara (which comes up at least 5 times in shas, as well as in the Yerushalmi & Midrash). I even found a [Korban nesanel in nedarim](https://www.sefaria.org/Korban_Netanel_on_Nedarim.28.5) that  writes "דבכמה מקומות כהנים נקראו לוים כמ"ש רש"י ביהושע ג" citing [Rashi in sefer Yoshua](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Joshua.3.3.2) rather than the Gemara. Interestingly, that Rashi quotes a בראשית רבה (which I did not see) as saying "במ"ח מקומות נקראו הכהנים לוים".)

### **2. [Ibn Ezra & Radak on Malachi 3:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Malachi.3.3?lang=bi&p2=Ibn_Ezra_on_Malachi.3.3.2&lang2=bi&p3=Radak_on_Malachi.3.3.2&lang3=bi)**

> **"וטהר את בני לוי - (ו)הם הכהנים"**

### **3. Devarim 18:6-8**

> .וכי־יבא **הלוי** מאחד שעריך מכל־ישראל אשר־הוא גר שם ובא בכל־אות נפשו אל־המקום אשר־יבחר יהוה
> ושרת בשם יהוה אלהיו ככל־אחיו **הלוים** העמדים שם לפני יהוה. חלק כחלק יאכלו לבד ממכריו על־האבות (ס)

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.18.6?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Deuteronomy.18.6.1&lang2=bi):

> וכי יבא הלוי. יָכוֹל בְּבֶן לֵוִי וַדַּאי הַכָּתוּב מְדַבֵּר, תַּלְמוּד לוֹמַר ושרת, יָצְאוּ לְוִיִּים שֶׁאֵין רְאוּיִין לְשֵׁרוּת (ספרי)

### **4. Yechezkel 48:11**

> לכהנים המקדש מבני צדוק אשר שמרו משמרתי אשר לא־תעו בתעות בני ישראל כאשר תעו הלוים

[Radak on Yechezkel 48:11 comments](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.48.11?lang=bi&p2=Radak_on_Ezekiel.48.11.2&lang2=bi):

> **כאשר תעו הלוים. ר"ל הכהנים הלוים שאינם מבני צדוק**

### **5. Yechezkel 44:10-31**

> כִּי אִם־**הַלְוִיִּם** אֲשֶׁר רָחֲקוּ מֵעָלַי בִּתְעוֹת יִשְׂרָאֵל אֲשֶׁר תָּעוּ מֵעָלַי אַחֲרֵי גִּלּוּלֵיהֶם וְנָשְׂאוּ עֲוֺנָם׃ וְהָיוּ בְמִקְדָּשִׁי מְשָׁרְתִים פְּקֻדּוֹת אֶל־שַׁעֲרֵי הַבַּיִת וּמְשָׁרְתִים אֶת־הַבָּיִת הֵמָּה יִשְׁחֲטוּ אֶת־הָעֹלָה וְאֶת־הַזֶּבַח לָעָם וְהֵמָּה יַעַמְדוּ לִפְנֵיהֶם לְשָׁרְתָם׃ יַעַן אֲשֶׁר יְשָׁרְתוּ אוֹתָם לִפְנֵי גִלּוּלֵיהֶם וְהָיוּ לְבֵית־יִשְׂרָאֵל לְמִכְשׁוֹל עָוֺן עַל־כֵּן נָשָׂאתִי יָדִי עֲלֵיהֶם נְאֻם אֲדֹנָי יְהוִה וְנָשְׂאוּ עֲוֺנָם׃ וְלֹא־יִגְּשׁוּ אֵלַי לְכַהֵן לִי וְלָגֶשֶׁת עַל־כָּל־קָדָשַׁי אֶל־קָדְשֵׁי הַקְּדָשִׁים וְנָשְׂאוּ כְּלִמָּתָם וְתוֹעֲבוֹתָם אֲשֶׁר עָשׂוּ׃ וְנָתַתִּי אוֹתָם שֹׁמְרֵי מִשְׁמֶרֶת הַבָּיִת לְכֹל עֲבֹדָתוֹ וּלְכֹל אֲשֶׁר יֵעָשֶׂה בּוֹ׃ (פ)
> וְהַכֹּהֲנִים הַלְוִיִּם בְּנֵי צָדוֹק אֲשֶׁר שָׁמְרוּ אֶת־מִשְׁמֶרֶת מִקְדָּשִׁי בִּתְעוֹת בְּנֵי־יִשְׂרָאֵל מֵעָלַי הֵמָּה יִקְרְבוּ אֵלַי לְשָׁרְתֵנִי וְעָמְדוּ לְפָנַי לְהַקְרִיב לִי חֵלֶב וָדָם נְאֻם אֲדֹנָי יְהוִה׃ הֵמָּה יָבֹאוּ אֶל־מִקְדָּשִׁי וְהֵמָּה יִקְרְבוּ אֶל־שֻׁלְחָנִי לְשָׁרְתֵנִי וְשָׁמְרוּ אֶת־מִשְׁמַרְתִּי׃ וְהָיָה בְּבוֹאָם אֶל־שַׁעֲרֵי הֶחָצֵר הַפְּנִימִית בִּגְדֵי פִשְׁתִּים יִלְבָּשׁוּ וְלֹא־יַעֲלֶה עֲלֵיהֶם צֶמֶר בְּשָׁרְתָם בְּשַׁעֲרֵי הֶחָצֵר הַפְּנִימִית וָבָיְתָה׃... כָּל־נְבֵלָה וּטְרֵפָה מִן־הָעוֹף וּמִן־הַבְּהֵמָה לֹא יֹאכְלוּ הַכֹּהֲנִים׃ (פ)

[Metzudas Tzion on Yechezkel 44:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.44.10?lang=bi&p2=Metzudat_Zion_on_Ezekiel.44.10.1&lang2=bi) writes:

> **"הלוים. ר״ל הכהנים בני לוי"**

---

### For examples of "כהנים לוים" meaning "כהנים" see [here](https://kehuna.org/twenty-four-places-the-kohanim-are-called-leviim/).